# Can I pass the "this" of my calling class into a lambda function?

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm using lambda functions as callbacks.

Quickie example:

```
class Something
{
public:
    int mValue=25;
    std::function<void()> mCallbackPtr;
    DoSomething()
    {
        mCallbackPtr(); // <- But I want "this" in the lambda function to point at 
                        //    this object, so that the code of the lambda function
                        //    acts just like it's an extension of this function.
    }
};

SomeCode()
{
    Something* MyThing=new Something;
    MyThing->mCallBackPtr = [=]() {cout << this->mValue;} // Since Something::DoSomething called
                                                          // this, I would like it to behave as
                                                          // if it was just an extension of
                                                          // Something.  Possible?
    MyThing->DoSomething();
}
```

So is what I have in the comments up there possible?  I'm trying to make a very flexible class that I can hook lambda functions right into to extend the class without having to inherit a whole new class.  I could pass "this" as an argument, but just for consistency, I'd love to be able to tell the lambda function to act like it's in scope of the calling function.

When I capture "this" it captures whatever is local where I declare the lambda function.  I'm trying to capture "this" at function call time, not definition time.

Can it be done?

Comment: You want code outside a class to be able to write code that runs just as if it was part of the class? Doesn't that completely break the idea of the class as an abstraction? Do you want the code to fail if `mValue` isn't `public`? Why not just replace `this` with `myThing`?

Comment: I wouldn't mind if it completely crashed in that case-- I expect to police myself.  Like I said, I can just pass Something* myThis as a parameter, but if it was possible to not have to do that, if some provision exists for this odd case, then I'd prefer to use that instead.

Comment: Well, yes, you can, [Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) see **Lambda capture** heading Nos. 7 & 8.

Comment: Better to capture `[this]` explicitly.

Comment: When I capture [this] it sends me "this" in the scope of the SomeCode() function (which is a class function in the real code I'm working with).  What I'm looking for is a way to re-point the "this" pointer in the lambda at the "this" of DoSomething()

Comment: Then the lambda needs to capture `MyThing` instead of `this`, or capture a reference to the object that `MyThing` points to.

Comment: Remy, is there a way to redirect that to "this?"  What I'm trying to do is make it seem like the lambda "hook" is just seamlessly an extension of DoSomething().  It's just for my own ease of use while coding.

Comment: You could also pass `this` as an argument.

Comment: Right-- I don't mind doing that.  But is there a way I can make it be the word "this" instead of some lame parameter variable name like myThis?

Comment: In my opinion, using the word 'this' in the lambda would be misleading and confusing in the context where the lambda is being defined.  It might make sense to you, but for someone else reading the code it would be unconventional and confusing.

Comment: I think it is somewhat unclear what you are really trying to do.  It is also important to keep  in mind that the callback function will extend some specific instance of your class, not the class itself.  If you have 5 instances of your class, you could define 5 different callback functions, each of which could be different.  Perhaps you really want to derive classes from your class, and add functionality to the base class using the mechanism you are describing.  In that context, 'this' would be usable in the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Since 'this' is a c++ keyword, it has functionality that is defined by the standard, so the answer is no, you can't use the word 'this' to mean something other than what 'this' means in the context where it is used.

In the context you are using it, this can't mean anything other than what it means.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this

In the context of extending a class, something like this is possible:

```
class animal {
public:
    std::string sound{ "" };
    std::function<void()> callback;
    void make_sound() { callback(); }
};

// a dog, which "is an animal"
class dog : public animal {
public:
    // construct, and "extend" animal by setting the callback
    dog() {
        // in this context, 'this' is appropriate
        callback = [&]() { this->sound = "bark"; };
    }
};

// a cat, which "is an animal"
class cat : public animal {
public:
    // construct, and "extend" animal by setting the callback function
    cat(){
        // in this context, 'this' is appropriate
        callback = [&]() { this->sound = "meow"; };
    }
};

void make_animal_sounds() {
    cat a_cat;
    dog a_dog;

    a_cat.make_sound();
    a_dog.make_sound();

    // in this context, an instance must be specified
    a_cat.callback = [&]() {a_cat.sound = "quack"; };

    // now a_cat will sound like a duck
    a_cat.make_sound();

}
```

Of course there are more conventional ways of extending a class, but maybe this is what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

> When I capture "this" it captures whatever is local where I declare the lambda function. I'm trying to capture "this" at function call time, not definition time.

That means, you did not capture it but you want to use it at the time you call your callback from the context of your class. Quite simply, pass "this" as parameter for your callback function!

```
class Something
{   
public:
    int mValue=25;

    // Change signature for your functional object, it now takes 
    // a pointer to your object which is "this" at calltime.
    std::function<void(Something*)> mCallbackPtr;

    void DoSomething()
    {   
        mCallbackPtr(this); // <- But I want "this" in the lambda function to point at
                        //    this object, so that the code of the lambda function
                        //    acts just like it's an extension of this function.
    }   
};  

int main()
{   
    // no need to create object on heap, use stack. 
    // avoids missing delete :-)
    Something MyThing;

    int anyVarToCapure = 77; 

    MyThing.mCallbackPtr = [=](Something* obj) 
    {   
        std::cout << anyVarToCapure << std::endl;
        std::cout << obj->mValue << std::endl;
    };  

    MyThing.DoSomething();
}
```